# El único error es que si por ejemplo pongo el dni del tercero con una calificación me devolverá el nombre del primero con esa calificación

Tags: c++

El programa devuelve error si el dni no coincide con ninguno. Pero si el dni coincide con el tercero por ejemplo, me devuelve el nombre y apellido del primero, El problema esta en la estructura for pero ya la he cambiado varias veces y no se como ponerla. Despues intente reducir el if a `DNI = usuarios[i].DNI` pero tampoco me deja aí que lo he dejado enumerado como lo veis.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

struct Usuario{
    string nombre;
    string apellidos;
    string DNI;
    double calificacion;
    bool DNIvalido;
     };
   string DNI;
Usuario usuarios[4];
usuarios[0].nombre="Juan";
usuarios[0].apellidos="Lopez";
usuarios[0].DNI ="44567234P";
usuarios[1].nombre= "Laura";
usuarios[1].apellidos ="Perez";
usuarios[1].DNI= "23456981F";
usuarios[2].nombre= "Carlos";
usuarios[2].apellidos ="Lopez";
usuarios[2].DNI= "44567342G";
usuarios[3].nombre= "Maria";
usuarios[3].apellidos ="Gutierrez";
usuarios[3].DNI= "44567342J";
cout<<"Introduzca su DNI por favor. " << "\n";
cin>> DNI;
for ( int i= 0; i<4 ;) {

if ( DNI == usuarios[0].DNI || DNI == usuarios[1].DNI || DNI == usuarios[2].DNI || DNI == usuarios[3].DNI ){
     
     double calificacion; 
    cout<<"Introduzca su calificacion por favor"<<"\n";
    cin>> calificacion;
    cout <<" El usuario "<< usuarios[i].nombre <<" "<< usuarios[i].apellidos
     << " tiene una calificacion de "<< calificacion << "\n";   
} else      {

    cout<<"DNI incorrecto, lo sentimos "<<"\n";
    break;
    
  }
   }    
  cin.get();
  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si creas un bucle para buscar el registro al que le corresponde el DNI, no necesitas comprobar manualmente el dni con TODOS los existentes:

```
for ( int i= 0; i<4 ;) {
    if ( DNI == usuarios[0].DNI || DNI == usuarios[1].DNI || DNI == usuarios[2].DNI || DNI == usuarios[3].DNI ){
    // ^^^^ MAL!!!
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es comprobar únicamente el registro que toque en cada momento ... para eso tienes el índice `i`.

EDITO: Se te ha olvidado incrementar i

```
for ( int i= 0; i<4 ;++i) {
//                   ~~~ <--- INCREMENTO

    if ( DNI == usuarios[i].DNI ){
        double calificacion; 
        cout<<"Introduzca su calificacion por favor"<<"\n";
        cin >> calificacion;
        cout <<" El usuario "<< usuarios[i].nombre <<" "<< usuarios[i].apellidos
     << " tiene una calificacion de "<< calificacion << "\n";   
    }
}
```

De la forma en la que lo has programado, cuando `i==0`, se comprobará si el DNI se corresponde con uno cualquiera de los 4 registros y, de ser así, el programa tratará **siempre** el primer registro como si fuese el buscado.

Para identificar un DNI erróneo necesitas un flag, ya que no puedes mostrar un mensaje de error hasta que no hayas recorrido todo el array. Piensa que no puedes saber si un DNI es incorrecto mirando únicamente la mitad de los registros:

```
bool dni_valido = false;
for ( int i= 0; i<4 ;++i) {
    if ( DNI == usuarios[i].DNI ){
        dni_valido = true;
        double calificacion; 
        cout<<"Introduzca su calificacion por favor"<<"\n";
        cin >> calificacion;
        cout <<" El usuario "<< usuarios[i].nombre <<" "<< usuarios[i].apellidos
     << " tiene una calificacion de "<< calificacion << "\n";   
    }
}

if (!dni_valido)
{
    cout<<"DNI incorrecto, lo sentimos "<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Si no compruebo manualmente todos los DNIs y lo pongo con el indice i entonces solo me funciona si escribo el DNI del primer usuario.

Comment: Como el indice i solo me funciona con el primer usuario al escribir cualquier DNI bien  el programa devolverá el "usuario 1 con  apellido 1" tiene una calificacion de

Comment: @AlexVasile he editado la respuesta ... no habia visto otro fallo

Comment: He incrementado i varias veces antes de subir el problema aquí y no creo que este el fallo ahi. He colgado la captura de pantalla para que se vea. Yo tambien creo que el programa esta bien porque no veo el fallo pero no funciona bien

Comment: @AlexVasile No te funciona porque has puesto el `if (!dni_valido)` **dentro** del bucle `for`, cuando te he dicho que tiene que estar **fuera**. No puedes saber que el DNI no es válido hasta que no hayas recorrido todo el array

Comment: cierto vale si ahora si que me identifica a los otros usuarios merciii